# Pandas: Add column using Numpy vectorization?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to replicate the following logic from Pandas, but using Numpy vectorization.

Also, I feel there might be a more Pythonic way of adding the `Actual Available` column without creating two separate variables `series_1` and `series_2` first, and also that is not verbose.

The logic behind `[Actual Available]` is,

- if [Is First?] column is True then `[Actual Available] = [Stock] + [Requirements] + [Receipts]`,
- if [Is First?] column is False then `[Actual Available] = [Prev row of Actual Available] + [Requirements] + [Receipts]`

Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Material": ["ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ"],
    "Plant": [2685, 2685, 2685, 2685, 2685, 2685, 2685],
    "Year": ["2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020"],
    "Week": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3],
    "Stock": [30, 30, 30, 30, 70, 70, 70],
    "Requirements": [10, 15, 20, 25, 20, 30, 40],
    "Receipts": [1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13]
})

print(df)

# Add [Is First?] column
df["Is First?"] = np.where(
    (df["Material"] == df["Material"].shift(1)) &
    (df["Plant"] == df["Plant"].shift(1)),
    False,
    True,
)

# Add [Actual Available] column
df["Actual Available"] = (df["Stock"] + df["Requirements"] +
                          df["Receipts"]).where(df["Is First?"].eq(True))

series_1 = df["Is First?"].eq(True).cumsum()
series_2 = (df["Actual Available"].ffill() +
            (df["Receipts"] +
             df["Requirements"]).shift(-1).groupby(series_1).cumsum().shift())

df["Actual Available"] = df["Actual Available"].fillna(series_2)

print(df)
```

Comment: What do you think adding `.eq(True)` does? Why the `False` and `True` in `numpy.where()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your initial DataFrame all of this logic seems to be a `groupby` + `cumsum` of 'Requirements' + 'Receipts' added to the 'Stock' column as 'Stock' is already repeated throughout the group.

```
df["Actual Available"] = df['Stock'] + df.groupby(['Material', 'Plant'])[['Requirements', 'Receipts']].cumsum().sum(1)
```

---

```
  Material  Plant  Year  Week  Stock  Requirements  Receipts  Actual Available
0      ABC   2685  2020     1     30            10         1                41
1      ABC   2685  2020     2     30            15         2                58
2      ABC   2685  2020     3     30            20         3                81
3      ABC   2685  2020     4     30            25         4               110
4      XYZ   2685  2020     1     70            20        11               101
5      XYZ   2685  2020     2     70            30        12               143
6      XYZ   2685  2020     3     70            40        13               196
```

---

In terms of "vectorization" `pandas` is built upon `numpy` so the performance is there. In addition `pandas` goes the extra mile for a lot of operations. `DataFrame.GroupBy.cumsum()` has a fast track implemented in `cython` so it's already been optimized a lot.